# вызов id через this

Tags: javascript

Скажите пожалуйста как вызвать id через this, в onclick  через js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 function myFunction(elem_id){ 
    console.log(elem_id);
  }
```

```html
<div style="width:20px;height:20px;background:#333" id="myDiv" onclick="myFunction(this.id)"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log(this.id);
});
```

```html
<div id="test">test<div>
```